# From Splash screen to Onboarding where I have 3 slides, then to Dashboard activity which ends up crashing not going through to dashboard

Tags: java, android, crash

I initialy had Radio player i.e RadioActivity, which was working perfectly
**The problem**
***I later decided to have a dashboad as the main activity where you can click a button to take you to the RadioActivty. Now app keeps crashing after splashscreen***

Find The Codes Below

**SplashScreen**

```
    private static int SPLASH_TIMER = 8000;

    ImageView backgroundImage;
    ImageView theLogo;
    TextView poweredByLine;

    Animation sideAnim, bottomAnim;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAGS_CHANGED,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);


        backgroundImage = findViewById(R.id.background_image);
        theLogo = findViewById(R.id.the_Logo);
        poweredByLine = findViewById(R.id.powered_by_line);

        sideAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.side_anim);
        bottomAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bottom_anim);

        backgroundImage.setAnimation(sideAnim);
        theLogo.setAnimation(sideAnim);
        poweredByLine.setAnimation(bottomAnim);


        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OnBoarding.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
        },SPLASH_TIMER);




    }
}
```

**OnBoarding**

```
    CardView nextCard;
    LinearLayout dotsLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;

    TextView[] dots;
    int currentPosition;
    SaveState saveState ;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_onboarding);

        nextCard = findViewById(R.id.nextCard);
        dotsLayout = findViewById(R.id.dotsLayout);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.slider);
        dotsFunction(0);
        saveState = new SaveState(OnBoarding.this,"OB");
        if (saveState.getState() == 1){
            Intent i = new Intent(OnBoarding.this,DashboardActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }

        OnBoardingAdapter adapter = new OnBoardingAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        nextCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPosition+1,true);
            }
        });
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(onPageChangeListener);

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void dotsFunction(int pos){
        dots = new TextView[4];
        dotsLayout.removeAllViews();

        for (int i = 0; i < dots.length ; i++){

            dots[i] = new TextView(this);
            dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("•"));
            dots[i].setTextColor(getColor(R.color.white));   //this is the non selection color
            dots[i].setTextSize(30);

            dotsLayout.addView(dots[i]);

        }

        if (dots.length > 0){
            dots[pos].setTextColor(getColor(R.color.teal_700));  //this is the selection color
            dots[pos].setTextSize(40);  //this is the selection size
        }
    }

    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener onPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            dotsFunction(position);
            currentPosition = position;
            if (currentPosition <= 2){
                nextCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPosition+1);
                    }
                });
            }else{
                nextCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        saveState.setState(1);
                        Intent i = new Intent(OnBoarding.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    };


}
```

**DashBoardActivity**

```
public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
   private ImageView imageViewWebsite,imageViewEvents,imageViewLive,
           imageViewVideos,imageViewBranches,imageViewDonate,
           imageViewEkuwe,imageViewRadio,imageViewAudio;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

       //defininf Cards
       imageViewWebsite = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.website_card);
       imageViewEvents = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.event_card);
       imageViewLive = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.live_card);
       imageViewVideos = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.videos_card);
       imageViewBranches = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.branches_card);
       imageViewDonate = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.donate_card);
       imageViewEkuwe = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ekuwe_card);
       imageViewRadio = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.radio_card);
       imageViewAudio = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.audio_card);

       //Add CLick listener to the card

       imageViewWebsite.setOnClickListener(this);
       imageViewEvents.setOnClickListener(this);
       imageViewLive.setOnClickListener(this);
       imageViewVideos.setOnClickListener(this);
       imageViewBranches.setOnClickListener(this);
       imageViewDonate.setOnClickListener(this);
       imageViewEkuwe.setOnClickListener(this);
       imageViewRadio.setOnClickListener(this);
       imageViewAudio.setOnClickListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent i;

       switch (v.getId()){
           case R.id.website_card : i = new Intent(this, WebsiteActivity.class);startActivity(i); break;
           case R.id.event_card : i = new Intent(this,EventsActivity.class);startActivity(i); break;
           case R.id.live_card : i = new Intent(this, LiveActivity.class);startActivity(i); break;
           case R.id.videos_card : i = new Intent(this, VideoActivity.class);startActivity(i); break;
           case R.id.branches_card : i = new Intent(this,BranchesActivity.class);startActivity(i); break;
           case R.id.donate_card : i = new Intent(this, DonateActivity.class);startActivity(i); break;
           case R.id.ekuwe_card : i = new Intent(this,EkuweActivity.class);startActivity(i); break;
           case R.id.radio_card : i = new Intent(this,RadioActivity.class);startActivity(i); break;
           case R.id.audio_card : i = new Intent(this,AudioActivity.class);startActivity(i); break;
           default:break;

       }

   }
}
```

**RadioActivity**

```
public class RadioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView nowPlaying;
    private ImageView playStop;
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
    private String nowPlayingData = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_radio);
        playStop = findViewById(R.id.playStopBtn);
        nowPlaying = findViewById(R.id.radioStationNowPlaying);
        setIsPlaying(false);
        processPhoneListenerPermission();
        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Service.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                if (tm != null) {
                    if (tm.getCallState() == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                        if (getIsPlaying()) {
                            stop();
                        }
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
        loadNowPlaying();
        playStop.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                if (getIsPlaying()) {
                    stop();
                } else {
                    play();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void loadNowPlaying() {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!isInterrupted()) {
                        runOnUiThread(() -> reloadShoutCastInfo());
                        Thread.sleep(20000);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }

    private void reloadShoutCastInfo() {
        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
            runner.execute();
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
            mmr.setDataSource(STREAMING_URL);
            nowPlayingData = mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ICY_METADATA).replaceAll("StreamTitle", "").replaceAll("[=,';]+", "");
            mmr.release();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            nowPlaying.setText(nowPlayingData);
        }
    }

    private void processPhoneListenerPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 121);
        }
    }

    public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = null;
        if (cm != null) {
            networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        }
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 121) {
            if (!(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission not granted.\nWe can't pause music when phone ringing.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", (dialog, id) -> {
                    if (getIsPlaying()) {
                        stop();
                    }
                    System.exit(0);
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", (dialog, id) -> dialog.cancel());
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    private void setIsPlaying(boolean status) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("isPlaying", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isPlaying", status);
        editor.apply();
    }

    private boolean getIsPlaying() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("isPlaying", MODE_PRIVATE);
        return prefs.getBoolean("isPlaying", false);
    }

    private void play() {
        setIsPlaying(true);
        Intent servicePlayIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        servicePlayIntent.putExtra("playStop", "play");
        startService(servicePlayIntent);
        playStop.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void stop() {
        setIsPlaying(false);
        Intent serviceStopIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        serviceStopIntent.putExtra("playStop", "stop");
        startService(serviceStopIntent);
        playStop.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stop Radio...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

**OnBoardingAdapter**

```
public class OnBoardingAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public OnBoardingAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    int titles[] = {
            R.string.title1,
            R.string.title2,
            R.string.title3,
            R.string.title4
    };

    int subtitles[] = {
            R.string.subtitle1,
            R.string.subtitle2,
            R.string.subtitle3,
            R.string.subtitle4
    };

    int images[] = {
            R.drawable.on_boarding_vector_1,
            R.drawable.on_boarding_vector_2,
            R.drawable.on_boarding_vector_3,
            R.drawable.on_boarding_vector_4
    };

    int bg[] = {
            R.drawable.bg1,
            R.drawable.bg2,
            R.drawable.bg3,
            R.drawable.bg4
    };

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return titles.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == (ConstraintLayout) object;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide,container,false);

        ImageView image = v.findViewById(R.id.slideImg);
        TextView title = v.findViewById(R.id.sliderTitle);
        TextView subtitle = v.findViewById(R.id.sliderSubtitle);
        ConstraintLayout layout = v.findViewById(R.id.sliderLayout);

        image.setImageResource(images[position]);
        title.setText(titles[position]);
        subtitle.setText(subtitles[position]);
        layout.setBackgroundResource(bg[position]);

        container.addView(v);

        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((ConstraintLayout) object);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this, I had to turn to Design Mode and Inspected everything i
found the problem on line 18 DashboardActivity.xml
I changed this
*com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar* to

**com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout**